# Display Formatted Mounted Partitions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

How can I display current mount points with a custom format?

I tried sending the output of `mount` through `sed`, but the slashes, parentheses, and other symbols get confusing quickly.

I can't quite get the regular expression right.  This still outputs the whole line:
`mount | sed -e 's/^\([^ ]*\) on \([^ ]* \) .*$/\2\t\1/'`

All I want is `MountDir<tab>MountDevice`.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: You need to show what you've tried.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Done

Comment: It works for me without space after '*', between second parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
mount | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }{ print $3, $1 }'
```

Sample output:

```
/sys    sysfs
/proc   proc
/dev    devtmpfs
/sys/kernel/security    securityfs
/dev/shm    tmpfs
/dev/pts    devpts
/run    tmpfs
```

These all have the tab character between them but they're not formatted great. I suspect you're looking for the `column` command.

```
mount | awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }{ print $3, $1 }' | column -t
```

Sample output:

```
/sys                             sysfs
/proc                            proc
/dev                             devtmpfs
/sys/kernel/security             securityfs
/dev/shm                         tmpfs
/dev/pts                         devpts
/run                             tmpfs
```